# Convert a String to bare text

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

```
list_one = [<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>]
```

I have an API function call that understands data like this in python.

```
my_api_function(list = [<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>])
```

However python won't accept this as the list is not defined properly.

How do I write the list as a string and still pass it in the function as written above?

EXPECTED RESULT

```
#SUDO CODE

list_one = ["<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>"]

list_one = list_one.convert_to_text # your solution comes here 

# Such that my_api_function passes as

my_api_function(list = [<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>])

#as oppose to

my_api_function(list = ["<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>]")

# Note that removing the quotes is my major issue
```

Comment: Sudo -> Pseudo.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you're trying to do. Would that work?
`text_data = "<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>"`
`list_one  = text_data.split(',')`
However, I don't think you can define an object in python with < / >

Comment: @Naktor. `<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>` is the repr of a cell object. You are right that this is code smell, but there's nothing fundamentally impossible about it.

Comment: the gspread api lets you populate a sheet with a data frame like the one above. However it gets really complicated, so I printed the list and it returned the list above. I can easily arrange my data like the above and upload

Comment: Your “data like this” is not valid Python syntax.  What does it mean that your target API “understands” it?  Do you just want that *string*?

Comment: "<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>" is description of a "Cell" object, but it is not a way of creating such an object.  You have to look to `gspread` to see how to create such an object.

Comment: A quick glance at `https://github.com/burnash/gspread` docs suggests that you could use `my_api_function(list = [worksheet.cell(1,1), worksheet.cell(1,2)])`, where `worksheet` is a `gspread` worksheat, created or loaded.

Comment: `[<Cell R1C1 'Hello'>, <Cell R1C2 'Name'>]` will cause a `SyntaxError` because it not valid Python.